# Creating one Node in Java changes the rest of them

Tags: java, nodes, modifier

I wrote a java Node class. It has the basics.

```
public class Node{
PuzzleState ps;
Node child;


public Node(PuzzleState ps){
    this.ps = ps;
}
public PuzzleState getState(){
    return this.ps;
}
public void setChild(Node n){
    this.child = n;
}
public Node getChild(){
    return this.child;
}

}
```

I created a new Node like this:

```
Node up = new Node(puzzle);
```

This will change all my other nodes to have all the characteristics of Node up. Please help me. I think I may be using the modifiers wrong (i.e. private, public, static)

Comment: Can you show me the other node creations too and what characteristics you mean.

Comment: How do you create `puzzle`? Note that `Node` does not copy/clone its `PuzzleState`, so if you accidentally share or later mess with that ...